# What type of font is used here?

Tags: fonts

What font is this?

[image: what font]

I saw it in a blog and I think it's really cute. So... have you any idea what font it's called?

Comment: Try [myfonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Huh???? Why closed as "off topic"??? Should be closed as a dupe???

Comment: @PeterGrill Sorted